# Running PHP cron job in new hook created in theme function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, scheduled-tasks

I created a hook in function.php in wordpress that I want to run every minute, and added the function in the hook with PHP code. At the same time, I use the WP-Control plugin to try to make this hook run every minute.
But when I set up the cron job in the plug-in, I found that even if the hook is run every minute, the function still does not work properly. I am a little confused about the reason of the function running.

Here is my php code:

```
// add autocheck function into a hook to get WP-Control
add_action( 'autocheck_run_every_minute', 'run_autocheck_every_minute' );

function run_autocheck_every_minute() {
    // add autocheck.php function in custom-auction into this method
        $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
    require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'     => '_stock_status',
                'value'   => 'instock',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => '_auction_has_started',
                'value'   => '1',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => '_auction_current_bid',
                'value'   => '',
                'compare' => '!=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => '_auction_current_bider',
                'value'   => '',
                'compare' => '!=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => '_reserved_option',
                //'value'   => '',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ), 
            array(
                'key'     => '_auction_dates_to',
                'value'   => date( "Y-m-d H:i" ), 
                'compare' => '<', // '>' auction still fresh, '<' auction ended!
            ),
        ),
    );

    //echo "1<br>";
    //print_r($args);
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        global $product;
        //$product_id = '7771';
        
        //$product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        if ($product->get_type() !== "auction"){
            return;
        }
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
        //echo $product_id;
        $user_id = get_post_meta($product_id, '_auction_current_bider', true);

        $auction_id = $product_id;
            
        $product_name = $product->get_name();
        $current_bid = $product->get_curent_bid();
        $reserve = get_post_meta($product_id, '_auction_reserved_price', true);
        $reserved_option = get_post_meta($product_id, '_reserved_option', true);
        if ((!isset($reserve)) || ($reserve == "") || (empty($reserve))){
            $reserve == 0;
        }
        $vendor_id = get_post( $auction_id )->post_author;
        //echo $vendor_id;
        $vendor = new WP_User( $vendor_id );
        //print_r($vendor);
        $vendor_recipient   = $vendor->user_email;
        //$vendor_name = $vendor->first_name." ".$vendor->last_name;  
        $vendor_name = $vendor->display_name;

        $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );
        $customer_recipient = $customer->get_email(); 
        //print_r($customer);
        //if ((!isset($reserved_option)) || ($reserved_option == "") || (empty($reserved_option))){
            if ($reserve <= $current_bid){
                //touch reserved price
                //echo $reserve - $current_bid;
                $data = array();
                $data['billing_first_name'] = $customer->get_billing_first_name();
                $data['billing_last_name']= $customer->get_billing_last_name();
                $data['billing_company']= $customer->get_billing_company();
                $data['billing_address_1']= $customer->get_billing_address_1();
                $data['billing_address_2']= $customer->get_billing_address_2();
                $data['billing_city']= $customer->get_billing_city();
                $data['billing_state']= $customer->get_billing_state();
                $data['billing_postcode']= $customer->get_billing_postcode();
                $data['billing_country']= $customer->get_billing_country();
                $data['billing_email']= $customer->get_email();
                $data['billing_phone']= get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', true );
        
                //print_r($data);
                //echo $product['name'] = $product->get_name();
                //print_r($product->get_tax_class()); 
                $taxes = WC_Tax::get_rates( $product->get_tax_class());
                $tota_tax_rate = 0;
                foreach($taxes as $tax){
                    $tota_tax_rate = $tota_tax_rate + $tax['rate'];
                    $tax_label = $tax['label'];
                }
        
        
                $data['taxes'] = $taxes;
                $data['product'][$product_id]['stock_status'] = $product->get_stock_status();
                $data['product'][$product_id]['price'] = $product->get_curent_bid();
                $data['product'][$product_id]['name'] = $product->get_name();
                $data['product'][$product_id]['type'] = $product->get_type();
                $data['product'][$product_id]['total_tax_rate'] = $tota_tax_rate;
                $data['product'][$product_id]['taxes'] = $taxes;
                $data['product'][$product_id]['sub'] = $sub = $product->get_curent_bid();
                $data['product'][$product_id]['sub_tax'] = $product_tax = round($product->get_curent_bid() * ($tota_tax_rate / 100), 2);
                $data['product'][$product_id]['sub_total'] = $subtotal = $product->get_curent_bid() + $product_tax;
                $data['product'][$product_id]['tax_class'] = $product->get_tax_class();
        
                //service fee:
                $service_fee = get_service_fee($user_id, $product_id, $product->get_curent_bid());
        
                $service_fee_tax = round($service_fee * ($tota_tax_rate / 100), 2);
                $service_fee_total = $service_fee + $service_fee_tax;
        
                $total = $product->get_curent_bid() + $product_tax ;
                $data['service_fee'][0]['amount'] = $service_fee;
                $data['service_fee'][0]['tax'] = $service_fee_tax;
                $data['service_fee'][0]['total'] = $service_fee;
                $data['service_fee'][0]['tax_class'] = $product->get_tax_class();
                $data['service_fee'][0]['taxes'] = $taxes;
        
                $data['total_before_tax'] = $sub + $service_fee;
                $data['total_tax'] = $product_tax + $service_fee_tax;
                $data['total'] = $subtotal + $service_fee_total;
                $result = CreateOrder($data, $user_id, $vendor_id);
                if(strpos($result, "error") == false){
                    $order_id = $result;
                }else{
                    return;
                }
                //print_r($order_id);
                
                $data_pdf = array();
                $data_pdf['order_id'] = $order_id;
                $data_pdf['tax_rate'] = $tota_tax_rate;
                $data_pdf['service_fee_total'] = $service_fee_total;
                $data_pdf['order_total'] = $subtotal + $service_fee_total;
                $data_pdf['order_subtotal'] = $sub + $service_fee;
                $data_pdf['order_GST'] = $tax_label=="GST"?$product_tax + $service_fee_tax:0;
                $data_pdf['order_PST'] = $tax_label=="PST"?$product_tax + $service_fee_tax:0;
                $data_pdf['customer_name'] = $customer_name = $customer->get_billing_first_name()." ".$customer->get_billing_last_name();
                $data_pdf['first_name'] = $customer->get_billing_first_name();
                $data_pdf['last_name'] = $customer->get_billing_last_name();
                $data_pdf['date'] = date("Y-m-d");
                $data_pdf['address'] = $customer->get_billing_address_1().$customer->get_billing_address_2();
                $data_pdf['city'] = $customer->get_billing_city();
                $data_pdf['postcode'] = $customer->get_billing_postcode();
                $data_pdf['phone'] = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', true );
                $data_pdf['username'] = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'nickname', true );
                //$data_pdf['invoice_number']
        
        
                $data_pdf['orders'][$order_id]['order_id'] = $order_id;
                $data_pdf['orders'][$order_id]['service_fee'] = $service_fee;
                $data_pdf['orders'][$order_id]['service_fee_PST'] = $tax_label=="PST"?$service_fee_tax:0;
                $data_pdf['orders'][$order_id]['service_fee_GST'] = $tax_label=="GST"?$service_fee_tax:0;
                
                
                
                $data_pdf['orders'][$order_id]['products'][$product_id]['product_name'] = $product->get_name();
                $data_pdf['orders'][$order_id]['products'][$product_id]['qty'] = 1;
                $data_pdf['orders'][$order_id]['products'][$product_id]['unit_price'] = $product->get_curent_bid();
                $data_pdf['orders'][$order_id]['products'][$product_id]['echo_PST'] = $tax_label=="PST"?$product_tax + $service_fee_tax:0;
                $data_pdf['orders'][$order_id]['products'][$product_id]['echo_GST'] = $tax_label=="GST"?$product_tax + $service_fee_tax:0;
                $data_pdf['orders'][$order_id]['products'][$product_id]['description'] = $product->get_short_description(); 
                //print_r($data_pdf); 
        
                $file = generate_new_pdf_download($data_pdf, "customer", 0, 0);
                $title = "Successful Bid on Reserved ".$product_name." at $".$current_bid." for Lot".$product_id;
                // print_r($title);
                //$dir = plugin_dir_path();
                //print_r($dir);
                $content = file_get_contents('/home/littl462/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-auction/templates/12_self_service_agree_bid_customer.html');
                //print_r($content);
                $content = str_replace('[product_id]',$auction_id, $content);
                $content = str_replace('[product_name]',$product_name, $content); 
                $content = str_replace('[current_bid]',$current_bid, $content);  
                $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
                wp_mail(
                    $customer_recipient,
                    $title,
                    $content,  
                    $headers,
                    $file,
                ); 
                //echo $auction_id."--".$product_name."--".$current_bid;
                //print_r($content);
                $profileid = get_user_meta($user_id, 'wc_authorize_net_cim_customer_profile_id', true);
                $paymentprofileid = json_decode(get_user_meta($user_id, 'wc_authorize_net_cim_customer_payment_id', true))[0];
        
                $service_fee_total = number_format($service_fee_total, 2);
        
                //echo gettype($service_fee_total); 
                $res = chargeCustomerProfile($profileid, $paymentprofileid, $service_fee_total);
        
                //die();
                if (!$res){
                    //pay failed
                    //echo "no";
                    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_auction_payment', "1" );
                    //failed payment first time sent email to buyer
                    $title = 'Failed Payment by Bidder';
                    //$dir = plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ );
                    $content = file_get_contents('/home/littl462/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-auction/templates/14_self_service_1st_payment_fail_customer.html');
                    $content = str_replace('[product_id]',$auction_id, $content);
                    $content = str_replace('[product_name]',$product_name, $content); 
                    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
                    wp_mail(
                        $customer_recipient,
                        $title,
                        $content,  
                        $headers,
                        
                    ); 
        
                    //failed payment first time sent email to seller
                    $title = 'Failed Payment by Bidder';
                    $content = file_get_contents('/home/littl462/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-auction/templates/16_self_service_1st_payment_fail_vendor.html');
                    $content = str_replace('[product_id]',$auction_id, $content);
                    $content = str_replace('[product_name]',$product_name, $content); 
                    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
                    wp_mail(
                        $vendor_recipient,
                        $title,
                        $content,  
                        $headers,
                        
                    );
        
                    
                }else{
                    
        
                    //pay successful
                    //echo "yes";
                    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_auction_payment', "TRUE" );
                    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        
                    if (!empty($order)) {
                        $order->update_status( 'wc-processing' );
                    }
        
                    //for customer
                    $title = 'Purchase Information of '.$product_name.' for Lot'.$product_id ;
                    $content = file_get_contents('/home/littl462/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-auction/templates/22_self_serivce_breach_customer.html');
                    $content = str_replace('[product_id]',$auction_id, $content);
                    $content = str_replace('[product_name]',$product_name, $content); 
                    $content = str_replace('[current_bid]',$current_bid, $content); 
                    $content = str_replace('[vendor_name]',$vendor_name, $content); 
                    $content = str_replace('[vendor_email]',$vendor_recipient, $content);
                    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
                    wp_mail(
                        $customer_recipient,
                        $title,
                        $content,  
                        $headers,
                        
                    ); 
        
                    //for vendor
                    $title =  'Sale Information of '.$product_name.' for Lot'.$product_id ;
                    $content = file_get_contents('/home/littl462/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-auction/templates/23_self_service_payment_success_vendor.html');
                    $content = str_replace('[product_id]',$auction_id, $content);
                    $content = str_replace('[product_name]',$product_name, $content); 
                    $content = str_replace('[current_bid]',$current_bid, $content); 
                    $content = str_replace('[customer_name]',$customer_name, $content); 
                    $content = str_replace('[customer_email]',$customer_recipient, $content); 
                    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
                    wp_mail(
                        $vendor_recipient,
                        $title,
                        $content,  
                        $headers,
                        
                    ); 
                    
                } 
        
            }else{
                //no touch resered price
                //echo $reserve - $current_bid;
                //for customer email
                $service_type = get_post_meta($auction_id, 'service_type', true);
        
                if ($service_type == "delegation"){
                    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
                    $headers[] = 'Cc:'.ADMIN_EMAIL;
                    $title = " High Bidder on Reserved on ".$product_name." for Lot ".$auction_id;
                    $content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ .'/templates/7_angeldd_no_reserve_customer.html');
                    $content = str_replace('[product_id]',$auction_id, $content);
                    $content = str_replace('[product_name]',$product_name, $content);
                    $content = str_replace('[current_bid]',$current_bid, $content);  
                    wp_mail(
                        $customer_recipient,
                        $title,
                        $content,  
                        $headers,
                    
                    );
        
        
                }else if ($service_type == "self_service"){
        
                    $title =  "High Bidder on Reserved ".$product_name." for Lot ".$auction_id;
                    $content_customer = file_get_contents('/home/littl462/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-auction/templates/9_self_service_no_reserve_customer.html');
                    $content_customer = str_replace('[product_id]',$auction_id, $content_customer);
                    $content_customer = str_replace('[product_name]',$product_name, $content_customer);
                    $content_customer = str_replace('[current_bid]',$current_bid, $content_customer); 
                    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
                    wp_mail(
                        $customer_recipient,
                        $title,
                        $content_customer,  
                        $headers,
                    
                    );
        
                    //for vendor email
                    //$vendor_recipient = $vendor->user_email;
                    $title =  "Reserve Not Met on Reserved ".$product_name." for Lot ".$auction_id;
                    $content_vendor = file_get_contents('/home/littl462/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-auction/templates/10_self_service_no_reserve_vendor.html');
                    $content_vendor = str_replace('[product_id]',$auction_id, $content_vendor);
                    $content_vendor = str_replace('[product_name]',$product_name, $content_vendor);
                    $content_vendor = str_replace('[current_bid]',$current_bid, $content_vendor); 
                    //$content_vendor = str_replace('[user_id]',$user_id, $content_vendor); 
                    $data = $product_id.OPTION_SPLITE.$user_id;
                    $data = _encrypt($data, OPTION_KEY);
                    $content_vendor = str_replace('[data]',$data, $content_vendor); 
                    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
                    //$headers[] = 'Cc:neo.itcg@gmail.com';
                    wp_mail(
                        $vendor_recipient,
                        $title,
                        $content_vendor,  
                        $headers,
                    
                    );
                    /* echo $data."--".$auction_id."--".$product_name."--".$user_id;
                    echo "<br>";
                    print_r($content_vendor); */
                    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_reserved_option', 'none' );
                }
                
                
        
            }

        /* }else{
            echo "1";
        } */

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Comment: WordPress’s cron, regardless of any plugin you install, runs in what is called “poor man’s cron” by default. This mode, especially on low traffic sites, or with certain types of caching, isn’t that precise, and might not even run when expected. Instead, [have the system (OS) run your cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/)

Comment: Use server cron over wp-cron since wp requires visitiing website every minute. Another option is to create a bot that visits your website every minute but i think its overkill for that.